# BitcoinCore walletnotify before blocknotify?

Tags: bitcoind, block, wallet-notify

I want to use bitcoind's `walletnotify` and `blocknotify` features. The question is:

Is `blocknotify` script **always** triggered **after** `walletnotify` script?

Imagine, I have an unconfirmed transaction in my wallet and I wait for a new block to arrive. When bitcoin node gets a new block, it has to fire both `walletnotify` for the first confirmation of my transaction and `blocknotify` for the block. Are all `walletnotify` events **always** fired **before** a `blocknotify` event?